# Apply Scala window function when condition is true else fill with last value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a set of transactions for various email ids. For example:

```
  val df = Seq(
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-01 01:04:00", "txid-0", false),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 01:04:00", "txid-1", true),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 02:04:00", "txid-2", false),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 03:04:00", "txid-3", true),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 04:04:00", "txid-4", false),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 04:05:00", "txid-5", false),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 05:04:00", "txid-6", true),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-05 12:04:00", "txid-7", true),
      ("b@gmail.com", "2020-12-03 03:04:00", "txid-8", true),
      ("c@gmail.com", "2020-12-04 06:04:00", "txid-9", true)
    ).toDF("email", "timestamp", "transaction_id", "condition")
```

What I am looking to get is the count of transactions grouped by email within the last 24 hours for which `condition` is true. If `condition` is false, I just want the `count` column to contain the last good count for which `condition` was true. For above, here is the result:

```
val expectedDF = Seq(
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-01 01:04:00", "txid-0", false, 0),
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 01:04:00", "txid-1", true, 1),
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 02:04:00", "txid-2", false, 1),// copy last count since condition is false
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 03:04:00", "txid-3", true, 2),
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 04:04:00", "txid-4", false, 2),// copy last count since condition is false
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 04:05:00", "txid-5", false, 2),// copy last count since condition is false
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 05:04:00", "txid-6", true, 3),
  ("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-05 12:04:00", "txid-7", true, 1), // beyond 24 hrs from prev transaction
  ("b@gmail.com", "2020-12-03 03:04:00", "txid-8", true, 1), // new email
  ("c@gmail.com", "2020-12-04 06:04:00", "txid-9", true, 1) // new email
).toDF("email", "timestamp", "transaction_id", "condition", "count")
```

What I did so far is:

```
    val new_df = df
      .withColumn("transaction_timestamp", unix_timestamp($"timestamp").cast(LongType))

    val winSpec = Window
      .partitionBy("email")
      .orderBy(col("transaction_timestamp"))
      .rangeBetween(-24*3600, Window.currentRow)

    val resultDF = new_df
      .filter(col("condition"))
      .withColumn("count", count(col("email")).over(winSpec))

    resultDF.show()
```

What this prints is the following without the rows with `condition`== false conditions but I want all the rows instead with proper count values like in `expectedDF`:

```
("email",      | "timestamp"         | "transaction_id" | "condition" | "count")
("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 01:04:00", "txid-1",           true,            1),
("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 03:04:00", "txid-3",           true,            2),
("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-02 05:04:00", "txid-6",           true,            3),
("a@gmail.com", "2020-10-05 12:04:00", "txid-7",           true,            1),
("b@gmail.com", "2020-12-03 03:04:00", "txid-8",           true,            1),
("c@gmail.com", "2020-12-04 06:04:00", "txid-9",           true,            1)
```

I am not able find a way to apply window function in a way that it only evaluates when condition is true else copies last good value when condition was last true. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create a extra column having value 1,0 for true,false and use cumulative sum...       `.filter(col("condition"))` can be removed

Comment: @undefined_variable, thanks for your comment. How will the extra column be used in the cumulative sum calculation? Could you please add an answer or add a comment? 
The accepted answer works for me but I have a few extra use cases for which I can apply your suggestion/method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not filter but just use the conditional expression by using `when`.

```
val resultDF = new_df
  .withColumn("count", count(when(col("condition"), col("email"))).over(winSpec))

resultDF.show()

+-----------+-------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-----+
|      email|          timestamp|transaction_id|condition|transaction_timestamp|count|
+-----------+-------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-----+
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-01 01:04:00|        txid-0|    false|         1.60151424E9|    0|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 01:04:00|        txid-1|     true|         1.60160064E9|    1|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 02:04:00|        txid-2|    false|         1.60160424E9|    1|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 03:04:00|        txid-3|     true|         1.60160784E9|    2|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 04:04:00|        txid-4|    false|         1.60161144E9|    2|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 04:05:00|        txid-5|    false|          1.6016115E9|    2|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-02 05:04:00|        txid-6|     true|         1.60161504E9|    3|
|a@gmail.com|2020-10-05 12:04:00|        txid-7|     true|         1.60189944E9|    1|
|c@gmail.com|2020-12-04 06:04:00|        txid-9|     true|         1.60706184E9|    1|
|b@gmail.com|2020-12-03 03:04:00|        txid-8|     true|         1.60696464E9|    1|
+-----------+-------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-----+
```

Comment: ,this doesn't work when I have `sum` in the place of `count`. In that case, it prints `null`. Is there a similar solution for `sum` as well?