# Spark window partition function taking forever to complete

Tags: scala, performance, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe, I am trying to compute how many times I have seen an emailId in the past 30 days. The main logic in my function is the following:

```
val new_df = df
  .withColumn("transaction_timestamp", unix_timestamp($"timestamp").cast(LongType))

val winSpec = Window
  .partitionBy("email")
  .orderBy(col("transaction_timestamp"))
  .rangeBetween(-NumberOfSecondsIn30Days, Window.currentRow)

val resultDF = new_df
  .filter(col("condition"))
  .withColumn("count", count(col("email")).over(winSpec))
```

The config:

```
spark.executor.cores=5
```

So, I can see 5 stages which have window functions in them, some stages out of those are completed very quickly (in a few seconds) and there are 2 that did not even finish in 3 hours, being stuck at the last few tasks(progressing very slowly):

This is a problem of data skew to me, if I remove all the rows containing the 5 highest frequency `email` ids from the dataset, the job finishes soon(less than 5 min).

If I try to use some other key within window partitionBy, the job finishes in a few minutes:

```
 Window.partitionBy("email", "date")
```

But obviously it performs wrong count calculations if I do that and it's not an acceptable solution.

**I have tried various other spark settings throwing more memory, cores, parallelism etc. and none of those have seemed to help**.

**Spark Version: 2.2**

Current Spark configuration:

-executor-memory: 100G

-executor-cores: 5

-driver memory: 80G

-spark.executor.memory=100g

Using machines each with 16 core, 128 gb memory. Maximum # of nodes up to 500.

What would be the right way to tackle this problem?

**Update:** Just to give more context, here is the original dataframe and the corresponding computed dataframe:

```
 val df = Seq(
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-10-01 00:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-02 01:04:00"), 
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-22 02:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-22 05:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-12-02 03:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-01-01 04:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-03-11 05:04:00"),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-04-05 12:04:00"),
      ("b@gmail.com", "2020-05-03 03:04:00")  
    ).toDF("email", "transaction_timestamp")


val expectedDF = Seq(
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-10-01 00:04:00", 1),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-02 01:04:00", 1), // prev one falls outside of last 30 days win
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-22 02:04:00", 2),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-11-22 05:04:00", 3),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2019-12-02 03:04:00", 3),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-01-01 04:04:00", 1),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-03-11 05:04:00", 1),
      ("a@gmail.com", "2020-04-05 12:04:00", 2),
      ("b@gmail.com", "2020-05-03 03:04:00", 1) // new email
).toDF("email", "transaction_timestamp", count")
```

Comment: Can you mention your Machine's Specification. ? Total cores and memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your partitions are probably too large which is due to the fact that for some emails, there is too much data in one month.

To fix this, you can create a new dataframe with only the emails and the timestamps. Then, you group by email and timestamp, count the number of lines and compute the window on hopefully much less data. The computation will be sped up if timestamps tend to be duplicated, that is if `df.count` is much greater than `df.select("email", "timestamp").distinct.count`. If it is not the case, you can truncate the timestamp at the cost of losing some precision. This way, instead of counting the number of occurrences within the last 30 days (give or take one second since timestamps are in seconds), you would count the number of occurrences give or take one minute or one hour or even one day depending on your need. You would lose a bit of precision but speed up you computation a lot. And the more precision you give in, the more speed you gain.

The code would look like this:

```scala
// 3600 means hourly precision.
// Set to 60 for minute precision, 1 for second precision, 24*3600 for one day.
// Note that even precisionLoss = 1 might make you gain speed depending on
// the distribution of your data
val precisionLoss = 3600 
val win_size = NumberOfSecondsIn30Days / precisionLoss

val winSpec = Window
  .partitionBy("email")
  .orderBy("truncated_timestamp")
  .rangeBetween(-win_size, Window.currentRow)

val new_df = df.withColumn("truncated_timestamp",
                      unix_timestamp($"timestamp") / 3600 cast "long")

val counts = new_df
  .groupBy("email", "truncated_timestamp")
  .count
  .withColumn("count", sum('count) over winSpec)

val result = new_df
  .join(counts, Seq("email", "truncated_timestamp"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Oli, this solution is awesome, but I still wonder why this runs faster when we lose some precision. Is it because it’s able partition data further? I find absolutely no documentation on how window functions work under the hood.

Comment: Looking at the physical query plan, it looks like it has to look back much smaller number of rows as compared to when there was no precision loss. That makes sense to me.

Comment: The way windows work under the hood is quite simple. When you partition by email, data is repartitioned by email, so there is a shuffle which is expensive. Then, to each email is associated a task, handled by one core on one machine. The tasks perform the window computation. Therefore if for one email there is much more data than for others, the corresponding task will take forever and so will the entire job, just waiting for one executor to finish his work.

Comment: This is why my first idea was to reduce the size of the windows but the results were disappointing. Here, the window computation is faster for two reasons. The dataframe has less columns so the records are smaller (we only keep two columns, maybe you had many which made the computattion even slower). But mainly, we reduce the size of the windows by aggregating the timestamps that are close together first. We reduce the window size and also the skew.

Comment: Hi there :) You've given the bounty, thanks by the way, but can you accept one of the answers so that we can consider the thread closed?

Comment: And if you have more issues like this one, don't hesitate to ping me. I really enjoyed working on this one even though I was quite disappointed that the 1st one failed to improve the performance ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You are right, this is a data skew issue and reducing the window size would help a lot. To get information about only the last 30 days, you do not need to go until the very beginning of times. Yet again, if build one window with a time index, the calculation will be wrong at the beginning of each window since it will not have access to the previous window.

What I propose is to build one index that is incremented every 30 days and two overlapping windows of size 60 days as shown in the following figure:

[image: overlapping windows]

To understand how this works, let's consider as shown on the figure a data point with `index=2`. If you had a window of size 30 days, it would need to access data within its window and within the previous one. That's not possible. This is why we build larger windows so that we can access all the data. If we consider `win1`, we have the same problem as with the index of size 30 days. If we consider `win2` however, all the data is available in the window of index 1.

For a point with index 3, we would use `win1`. For a point with index 4, `win2` etc. Basically, for even indices, we use `win2`. For odd indices, we use `win1`. This approach will considerably reduce the maximum partition size and thus the maximum amount of data handled in one single task.

The code is just a translation of what was explained above:

```scala
val winSize = NumberOfSecondsIn30Days

val win1 = Window
    .partitionBy("email", "index1")
    .orderBy(col("transaction_timestamp"))
    .rangeBetween(-winSize, Window.currentRow)
val win2 = Window
    .partitionBy("email", "index2")
    .orderBy(col("transaction_timestamp"))
    .rangeBetween(-winSize, Window.currentRow)

val indexed_df = new_df
    // the group by is only there in case there are duplicated timestamps,
    // so as to lighten the size of the windows
    .groupBy("email", "transaction_timestamp")
    .count()
    .withColumn("index",
        'transaction_timestamp / winSize cast "long")
    .withColumn("index1",
        ('transaction_timestamp / (winSize * 2)) cast "long")
    .withColumn("index2",
        (('transaction_timestamp + winSize) / (winSize * 2)) cast "long")

val result = indexed_df
    .withColumn("count", when(('index mod 2) === 0, sum('count) over win2)
                                      .otherwise(sum('count) over win1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Oli, I am not sure I follow the division of timestamp by winSize logic. Please look at the example dataframe I added to the problem statement. Would you code still work?

Comment: I realize I had forgotten the window declarations. I edited my answer. It produces the same result as your code.

Comment: BTW, there is an error in your example. for this timestamp `"2020-01-01 04:04:00"`, you expect `2`. But the previous timestamp is `"2019-12-02 03:04:00"` which is 30 days and 1 hour before. Therefore it is outside of the window and the correct result is `1`.

Comment: This is a great idea @Oli  for distributed data across months. But will this handle the case if data is skewed and present mostly for a single month?

Comment: No ;-) This trick is meant to handle the case for which some emails have much more data than others, but with records spread rather evenly across time. If that's not the case, we would need additional tricks, possibly joins. The approach would need to be even more elaborate, that's for sure.

Comment: True! But this is a nice trick , Upvoted.  I have implemented one Join method. Do have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli, this seems to be working. I am still have trouble visualizing this. 
2 minor questions: 1) the single quotes within `when` seem to be at weird places, but code still works. Is that a separate terminology/language you are using in the condition? 2)If I have to add more filter conditions like in this previously asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64086747/apply-scala-window-function-when-condition-is-true-else-fill-with-last-value , where exactly can I put it so as to filter further?If I put along with `when` in your snippet, it gives wrong values of the count.

Comment: About concern no1, `'index` means the column named index like `col("index")` or `$"index"`. About concern no2, to do the same thing as in this other question and if I understand correctly, replace both `count('*)` by `count(when(condition, '*))`.

Comment: Thanks Oli. Unfortunately, the spark job still got stuck on stage of first window. It has been running for more than 45 min, being stuck on the same task. There is another window that's not even started yet.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. Could it be that, as Sanket mentioned it, the time dimension is skewed as well? I mean for the emails with lots of data, do you have months with much more data than others?

Comment: I added a group by. If you have duplicated timestamps, that may help. Let me know if that helps. If not, we'll think of something else.

Comment: Thanks Oli for being so helpful, really appreciate it! I will check for time skewness, but usually that shouldn't be the case. Job has been running for past 4 hours, looks like it would finish within another hour. I will try `groupby` suggestion as well, why do you have a `count()` nex to it?Also, another issue I see is that the DAG has 2 window stages now, and they are running sequentially. I wish we could parallelize two stages containing the window functions, but when I write separate statements(one for odd and another for even case, thinking both can be parallelized), the counts are wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the result of `indexed_df.join( df.groupBy("email").count.orderBy('count desc).limit(1).select("email"), Seq("email")).groupBy("index").count.orderBy('count desc).show` ? The goal is to identify the distribution of the months for the email with the maximum amount of data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223075/discussion-between-ic10503-and-oli).

Comment: I added the source data distribution aggregated over each month on the chat discussion page(since it would be formatted poorly here).

Answer (score 2):

We can still avoid Window for this

For the above mentioned df

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp($"transaction_timestamp").cast(LongType))

val df3 = df2.withColumnRenamed("timestamp","timestamp_2").drop("transaction_timestamp")

val finalCountDf = df2.join(df3,Seq("email"))
.withColumn("is_within_30", when( $"timestamp" - $"timestamp_2" < NumberOfSecondsIn30Days && $"timestamp" - $"timestamp_2" > 0 , 1).otherwise(0))
.groupBy("email","transaction_timestamp").agg(sum("is_within_30") as "count")
.withColumn("count",$"count"+1)

finalCountDf.orderBy("transaction_timestamp").show
/*
+-----------+---------------------+-----+
|      email|transaction_timestamp|count|
+-----------+---------------------+-----+
|a@gmail.com|  2019-10-01 00:04:00|    1|
|a@gmail.com|  2019-11-02 01:04:00|    1|
|a@gmail.com|  2019-11-22 02:04:00|    2|
|a@gmail.com|  2019-11-22 05:04:00|    3|
|a@gmail.com|  2019-12-02 03:04:00|    3|
|a@gmail.com|  2020-01-01 04:04:00|    1|
|a@gmail.com|  2020-03-11 05:04:00|    1|
|a@gmail.com|  2020-04-05 12:04:00|    2|
|b@gmail.com|  2020-05-03 03:04:00|    1|
+-----------+---------------------+-----+
*/
```

Explanation :

- Make pairs of the timestamps based on "email" (join on email)
- Compare each pair and check if it lies within the last 30 days : If so mark it as 1 other wise 0
- Sum up the counts WRT "email" and "transaction_timestamp"

Assumption : (Email, transaction_timestamp) is distinct. If not, we can handle by adding a monotonicallyIncreasingId

Comment: Thanks @Sanket9394, the problem is I need to compute this count for each row. I am not sure if this would be possible without using a window function like you did. Please look at the dataframe I added to the problem statement.

Comment: Also, you are trying to find which rows are within the last 30 days from current(present) time, but it should be from the transaction timestamp instead.

Comment: @ic10503
I have edited my answer. Can you check now. This will ensure all your 5 cores are getting equal amount of Load.

Comment: Also, 
If you have more cores, please use them. `Increasing the no of cores` will help reduce run time for this method, but will be a bottle neck for `window` for skewed data

Comment: @Sanket9394, I am confident that your approach works as expected. Yet, I fear that with a skewed distribution over the emails, this will not solve the problem. It might even worsen it. Indeed, if we call M the maximum number of records for one email, the approach of the question generates a largest partition of size M, with your approach, it is going to be M^2. If you replace the when by a filter, it could go down to M^2/2 but still, I am not sure this is the way to tackle the skew.

Comment: I agree on your point. But this will scale with more resources , which window might have an issue.

Comment: @Sanket9394 Thanks! I wonder why you say that window function would not scale with more resources but join would. Is there some architectural constraint that Spark has? Only thing I can think of is the 2GB limit that Spark imposes on internal data structures like shuffle block etc.

Comment: @ic10503, one partition can be handled/worked only by 1 core/task. So, let's say if you have skewed data and unfortunately when you use window with a `partitionBy` such that huge portion of the data lies in one partition, then only 1 core will be used, and rest all will be idle. Basically less parallelism.

Comment: You need to identify the skew in your data. If it's just skewed with email but it's somewhat evenly distributed across months, then @Oli's solution would be best.